# MySQL variable value not changing in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, variables, intervals

My variable `@row_number` value is not changing in `WHERE` clause but is updated in `SELECT` clause

```
SET @row_number := -1;

SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number+1) as num,location_table.* FROM location_table
WHERE loc_userID = 'SP_EGMA001'
      AND (loc_date >= (STR_TO_DATE('05-27-2019 6:00:00', '%m-%d-%Y %H:%i:%s') + INTERVAL (30 * @row_number) minute))
ORDER BY loc_date asc
```

Answer (score 0):

try this - access the @row_number alias num in a outer query. excuse for any syntax errors.

```
SET @row_number := -1;

select * from (
SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number+1) as num,location_table.* FROM location_table
WHERE loc_userID = 'SP_EGMA001' ) a
WHERE (loc_date >= (STR_TO_DATE('05-27-2019 6:00:00', '%m-%d-%Y %H:%i:%s') + INTERVAL (30 * num) minute))
ORDER BY loc_date asc
```

Comment: can you just try with a standalone row_number (num) condition alone instead of mixing it with up date field to see if it works. e.g. replace the WHERE clause to just WHERE num > 3